# How to set apache ab pacing?

Tags: apache, rest, performance-testing, apachebench

Now I want to use apache bench to test my rest api performance.

I want to know how many requests my server can process per second.

So I want to do like following steps with apache bench:

500 requests per second,

1000 request per second,

15000 request per second ...

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you.

```
ab -s 9999 -k -c 2000 -n 30000 HTTP_API_URL
```

here is

- ab => apache benchmarking notaion.
- -s timeout  =>    Seconds to max. wait for each response                    Default is 30 seconds
- -k  =>    Use HTTP KeepAlive feature
- -n requests =>    Number of requests to perform
- -c concurrency =>  Number of multiple requests to make at a time

Comment: But I still don't see the pacing parameter.

Comment: Here pacing parameter is -c which put bundle of requests per second to server. for example if you request  2000 concurrent request per second to server and if there is no failed request in response you received that means your server is capable of handling that 2000 requests. 

you can use -t parameter also, like 60 for one minute and can check how many request are completed, than divide the result by 60

In response, " Requests per second:    50.91 [#/sec] (mean) ", that basically provide you number of requests completed in one second by the server.